# Dropdown not firing event on usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdown` list which is inside a user control on my page.
When I select an item in a `gridview` it fills some data including this dropdown list selecting the correspondent value to the `gridview row`.

Then I can change the selection, but when i try to do that the Selected Index Changed event isn't firing. At least not at first. If i select again it fires.

I'm using asp.net with `VB`. 
I have put `AutoPostback = true`, I've set the Handles in the codebehind method, I've set a default empty line and set it to default selection, but I can't get it to work.

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack() Then
        fillProd()
        Dim cert As String = Session("var")
        isFilled = Session("isFilled")

        If Not IsNothing(cert) And Not isFilled Then
            FillFields(cert)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub fillProd()
    dt = HttpContext.Current.Session("dt")
    Dim row() As DataRow = dt.Select()
    Dim dtProductos As New DataTable()
    dtProductos.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("valorcombo", GetType(String)))
    dtProductos.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("textocombo", GetType(String)))
    Dim firstrow As DataRow = dtProductos.NewRow()
    firstrow (0) = 0
    firstrow (1) = ""
    dtProductos.Rows.Add(firstrow)
    For i As Integer = 0 To row.Length - 1

        Dim fila As DataRow = dtProductos.NewRow()
        fila(0) = row(i)("cod")
        fila(1) = row(i)("text")
        dtProductos.Rows.Add(fila)
    Next

    ddlproductos.DataSource = dtProductos
    ddlproductos.DataTextField = "textocombo"
    ddlproductos.DataValueField = "valorcombo"
    ddlproductos.DataBind()
    ddlproductos.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
Private Sub FillFields(cert As String)
    Dim dtSubsData As DataTable = GetData(cert)

    If Not IsNothing(dtSubsData) Then
        Dim row As DataRow = dtSubsData.Rows(0)
        ddlproductos.ClearSelection()
        ddlproductos.SelectedValue = row("cod").ToString()
        Session("isFilled") = True
        isFilled = Session("isFilled")
    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you databind the gridview on every postback? Is something added programmatically?

Comment: Actually yes it's binding on every postback. I tried to remove it but it didn't work. Can that be the problem?

Comment: If you databind it on every postback that'll prevent events from being trigerred. Why can't you do this only `If Not Page.IsPostBack`?

Comment: Just tried that. The datagrid came out empty... weird. Looks like the control allways posts back

Comment: You need to show us some code. What means "the control always posts back"? Which _control_?

Comment: just edited my post with some code. I have the code on a User Control (ascx), so the control I mean is that one